# Download dentro da app

Tags: android, app, download, image

O meu aplicativo e conjunto de imagens, gostava de saber como posso criar um botão que permita salvar as imagens no telefone ou colocar as imagens como fundo do telefone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite, bom, se você pegar o Bitmap, é possível salvar ele facilmente na galeria usando o `MediaStore`

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
        <SEU_BITMAP>, <TITULO> , <DESCRICAO>);
```

contudo, no android 5.0 em diante é necessário pedir permissão antes, além de colocar no seu manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

e para a requisição no android:

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE)
```

somando tudo:

```
final int REQUEST_CODE = 110;
public void salvaImagem(){
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
                <SEU_BITMAP>, <TITULO> , <DESCRICAO>);
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        salvaImagem();
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela sua ajuda, estou iniciando nesta area.